# post id in next page in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have function.php script that open page using php curl function it working correctly but i have a problem i want to post $id in next page but i don't know how can i post  $id in next page..here is the code

```
            function fire_script($script,$id,$buffer_output=1)
            {
             if(($buffer_output) AND (!DEBUG)) ob_start();//buffer output 
             $scriptRunning = new scriptStatus;
             $scriptRunning->script=$script;
             if ($scriptRunning->Running($id) )
             {
                  if (DEBUG) echo "<br>Now running: $script - id=$id (debug ref. 3.9b)<br>";
                  $start_time = microtime(true);
                  $fire_type = (function_exists('curl_exec') ) ? " PHP CURL " : " PHP fsockopen ";
                  //                 "://" satisfies both cases http:// and https://
                  if (strstr($script,"://") ) fire_remote_script($script);
                  else
                   {
                     include(LOCATION.$script);
                     $fire_type=" PHP include ";
                   }
                  if(($buffer_output) AND (!DEBUG)) 
                  {
                    $scriptRunning->output=ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();
                  }
                  if (!$buffer_output) $scriptRunning->output="";
                  $scriptRunning->execution_time=number_format( (microtime(true) - $start_time), 5 )." seconds via".$fire_type;
                  $scriptRunning->Stopped($id);
             }
            }
```

and my $script is $script='http://localhost/test.php';

and my test.php is....

```
    <?php
    include("functions.php");
    $id=clean_input($_GET['id']);

    $dbc = dbc::instance();
    $result = $dbc->prepare("select * from product where id='$id' ");
    $rows = $dbc->executeGetRows($result);
    $id= $row["id"];
    echo "My id is "$id;
    ?>
```

Comment: Which page you want to send `$id` to?

Comment: i want to send it in test,php

Comment: is it possible to send id through link like http://localhost/test.php?id=1 .

Comment: If you want to get this `$id` field in `test.php` page then you can do this.

Comment: You know in your first script, where are you telling it to go to the 'testpage'?

Answer (score 0):

**Your:**

```
$script = http://localhost/test.php
```

**Should be like this:**

```
$script = http://localhost/test.php?bid=$id
```

**And then your:**

`$_GET`

Will work in your 'testpage.php'